# Which is correct: "tattoo in the chest" vs "tattoo on the chest"?

Tags: prepositions

I've seen different people using expression "tattoo in the chest" vs "tattoo on the chest". Which one is the correct one?

I can imagine both options having some sense because tattoo ink is inserted inside the skin but the finished tattoo is visible on the skin.

How about if you're wearing a shirt with text on it? Is that "text in the chest" or "text on the chest"?

Comment: I would find _in the chest_ odd in both cases.

Comment: I agree with Kate.  *In* usually means *inside*.  Your lungs are *in* your chest, but your tattoo is *on* your chest.

Comment: Perhaps a tattoo *in the armpit,* or *iside an ear,* might make sense, but it is *on* the chest. [Yes, a few microns below the surface, but still considered "on".]